# Save croped copy of original image while upload with Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make function which save cropped thumb of image and the original. Purpose is to show on the page smaller version so the page will load fast and when user click on image the original is opened into lightbox.

I'm using [php-image-resize](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize). This is what I've tried and what I have so far.

```
   public function uploadSubmit() {

        $file = Input::file('image');
        $image = new ImageResize($file);

        $gallery = new Gallery;
        $filename = str_random(20) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $thumb = $filename . '-thumb.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $file->move('uploads', $filename);
        $imagePath = '/uploads/' . $filename;


        $image->crop(200, 200);
        $image->save('/uploads/' . $thumb); 

        $gallery->image = $imagePath;
        $gallery->image_path = $image;
        $gallery->image_name = strip_tags(Input::get('image_name'));
        $gallery->save();

        return Redirect::to('/admin/upload')->with('message', 'Image added.');     
    }
```

When I run the page I've got the error

> 'ErrorException' with message 'imagejpeg(/uploads/44Bsl9HybTvFLpKIYcdL.jpg-thumb.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

The part which should crop the image is

```
    $image = new ImageResize($file);

    $thumb = $filename . '-thumb.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();           
    $image->crop(200, 200);
    $image->save('/uploads/' . $thumb);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update: working source

```
$file = Input::file('image');
$image = new ImageResize($file);


$gallery = new Gallery;
$filename = str_random(20);

$original = $filename  . '.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$thumb = $filename . '-thumb.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$file->move('uploads', $original);

$imagePath = 'uploads/' . $original;
$thumbPath = 'uploads/' . $thumb;

$image->crop(200, 200);
$image->save('uploads/' . $thumb);  

$gallery->image = $imagePath;
$gallery->image_path = $thumbPath;
$gallery->image_name = strip_tags(Input::get('image_name'));
$gallery->save();
```

Comment: Try removing the leading slash from `$imagePath = '/uploads/' . $filename;` and use `$imagePath` in this line `$image->save($imagePath . $thumb);`

Comment: Thank's.Now it is saving both images but in database doesn't save name of cropped one. This line: `$gallery->image_path = $image;`

Comment: Surely that should be `$gallery->image = $image;` and `$gallery->image_path = $imagePath;`

Comment: Or rather why are you saving the image to the database as you have saved both images to disk?

Comment: `$gallery->image = $imagePath;` is original image and `$gallery->image_path = $image;` is thumb. Thank's for the help. I fixed it and now is working

Comment: I saving the name and path only..

Comment: `$image` is not just the name, its an object. Does it have a name property?

Comment: Or maybe you shoudl be using `$file->getClientOriginalName()`

Comment: I've updated my question with working code.